# Show image on preview before uploading to server in android

Tags: android, image, kotlin, retrofit, android-image

I'm working with images in kotlin and I'm trying to upload an image to server using retrofit. But before uploading I wanted to show image on preview. I've been reading about how to do this but still didn't find the right solution. 
here is my code until this moment

```
fun chooseImageFromGallery() {
    val galleryIntent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI)
    startActivityForResult(galleryIntent, GALLERY)
}

private fun takePhotoFromCamera() {
    val cameraIntent = Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE)
    startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, CAMERA)
}


override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)

    if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK)
        when(requestCode){
            GALLERY -> {
                val selectedImage: Uri = data!!.data



            }
        }
}
```

Please help me!

Comment: You can use glide to handle that image and display it.

Answer (score 0):

To preview image after selecting an image from the gallery or by capturing an image from phone camera can be done using various libraries like Picasso, Glide, Fresco etc or else you can convert it into bitmap image and set directly to ImageView

```
  override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: 
   Intent?) {
       super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)

       if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK)
       when(requestCode){
          GALLERY -> {
            val selectedImage: Uri = data!!.data
            Picasso.get().load(selectedImage).into(imageView2);//Using Picasso            
            Glide.with(this).load(selectedImage).into(imageView2);//Using Glide

          }

         }
    }
```

Comment: I want to show on preview first, if you can help me with this I would be very grateful :) Thank you for the answer anyway @Ravi Kumar

Comment: Camera app itself gives you the ability to review/retake the image after capturing the image, and once an image is accepted, then you can able to crop the image if you wish. If you still need to show preview after that open a separate activity and show this result image  in that activity

Answer (score 0):

If you want to display thumbnail image just for preview you can get it using below code.

```
override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent) {
    if (requestCode == REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        val imageBitmap = data.extras.get("data") as Bitmap
        imageView.setImageBitmap(imageBitmap)
    }
}
```

You can refer to complete implementation [here](https://developer.android.com/training/camera/photobasics#kotlin) on android developers site.